# VirtualBox E_FAIL (0x80004005) when trying to run Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to make a Ubuntu VM, but it keeps giving me this error: 
The virtual machine 'ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Chopto\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}

I'm on Windows 10, I have a Ryzen 1700 CPU with AMD-V enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating to Virtual Box version 5.2.8 fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my VirtualBox to 6.04 version.

Deleted the virtual machine of already installed. (.vbox still exists in my storage)

Added virtual machine from the storage again, solved my problem.